# Fastest way to fill a matrix with Random bytes

Tags: c#, random, multidimensional-array

I want to **fill an array with random values**. The code I wrote is this one:

```
public class PersonalityMap
{
    const int size = 16;
    byte[,] fullMap = new byte[size, size];

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a random map
    /// </summary>
    public PersonalityMap()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        byte[] row = new byte[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            random.NextBytes(row);
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                fullMap[i, j] = row[j];
        }
    }
}
```

But I feel there's a way to do it faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you could create one single-dimensional array, fill that, and then copy it with Buffer.BlockCopy:

```
Random random = new Random();
byte[] row = new byte[size * size];
random.NextBytes(row);
Buffer.BlockCopy(row, 0, fullMap, 0, size * size);
```

However, before you try to optimize even further - just how quick do you need this to be? Have you benchmarked your application and determined that this is the bottleneck of your application?

Comment: True, I think the bottleneck wont be here but I've just started writting the application and I want to start doing it well. Thanks Jon.

Comment: @JaimeOro premature optimizations are often bad.

Answer (score -1):

Jagged arrays (arrays of arrays) are consider faster than multidimensional arrays, **but** you will get speed up of a few ms. Is this worth it?

This optimization is not worth to spend your time on it.